# How to ignore KeyboardInterrupt in python?

Tags: python

I'am writing console program. I want that save flow may break with Cntr-c only after answer on question: Do you really want break it?

```
def sigint_handler(signal, frame):
    try:
        Exit = (str(raw_input("Break ? Y/N")))
        if Exit == "Y" or Exit=="y":
            raise KeyboardInterrupt()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        raise KeyboardInterrupt()
    except Exception as e:
        pass

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,sigint_handler)
i=0

while i<1000:
    i=i+1
    print "%d\n"%i
    sleep(0.5)
```

It's fail if I try cntl+c instead of Y:

> 71
>
> 72
>
> 73
>
> 74
>
> 75
>
> ^CBreak ? Y/Ny
>
> File "/home.local/valerys/rde_1_3/rdepyui/bin/../api/cli.py", line
>   48, in sigint_handler
>       Exit = (str(raw_input("Break ? Y/N"))) RuntimeError: can't re-enter readline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you make a re-raise of `KeyboardInterrupt` in the `except` block? In this way you catch the first `KeyboardInterrupt` but you don't have another try/except block for catching the second. Maybe a better solution is to call

```
try:
    Exit = (str(raw_input("Break ? Y/N")))
    if Exit == "Y" or Exit=="y":
        raise KeyboardInterrupt()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()
```

for a clean exit strategy.
I hope this can help you.

Comment: why not exiting directly, without raising the exception?

Comment: @Pynchia : I suppose that this exception raise is needed to other purpose not shown in this simplified version of code but, other this, I don't see any reason to raise this exception.

Comment: It's CLI and I want that user doesn't cancel execution of program flow.